# Combine two collections without looping

Tags: laravel, collections

How can I combine two collections without using any of iterative collection methods?

I have the following:

```
$stores = collect([
    ['store_id'=> 5, 'name' => 'test1'],
    ['store_id'=> 33, 'name' => 'test2'],
    ['store_id'=> 7, 'name' => 'test3'],
]);

$estimations = [
    33 => ['minutes' => 40],
    5 => ['minutes' => 30],
    7 => ['minutes' => 25]
];
```

I want the result to be like:

```
[
    ['store_id'=> 5, 'name' => 'test1', 'minutes' => 30],
    ['store_id'=> 33, 'name' => 'test2', 'minutes' => 40],
    ['store_id'=> 7, 'name' => 'test3', 'minutes' => 25],
]
```

**without** using any iterative methods like `transform` or `map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the keys in the `$estimations` array are supposed to correspond to the `store_id` value in the collection, I think you can use `replaceRecursive()` if you key the collection by store_id.

```
$result = $stores->keyBy('store_id')->replaceRecursive($estimations)->values();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge()` method from Laravel Collection's.

```
$collection = collect(['product_id' => 1, 'price' => 100]);

$merged = $collection->merge(['price' => 200, 'discount' => false]);

$merged->all();
```

As said in the Laravel Docs: "**If a string key in the given items matches a string key in the original collection, the given item's value will overwrite the value in the original collection**".

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-merge